# Which humanities journals publish original research?

Tags: journals, humanities

I was recommended to publish the results of my research, but the recommended articles include only review articles and if I asked them, whether I could send an original research paper, the answer was unclear:

1. "This structure makes very little sense for humanities articles, although social science original research often uses the structure that is more commonly found in science and medical fields."([for WikiJournal of Humanities](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Talk:WikiJournal_of_Humanities#Original_research_structure))
2. "Every published text must be the original author's text. The use of appropriate professional methodology is therefore desirable."(for Brno in the past and today)

As time is the most expensive commodity for me, I cannot afford to blindly test whether the original research will pass and I need to eliminate possible missteps. I believe in the generally known principle that those who write an article similar to the articles in the given journal have a better chance of the article being accepted. So do you know of any journals where original research on the topic of central European art or humanities could be published?

Comment: This is research you need to do yourself. You know your article better than anyone on this forum, and since you have written an article on your topic you have an idea of the state of the literature on that exact topic. So you already know what journals publishes your type of articles, and you know it better than any of us could know.

Comment: I do not understand.  Go look at the web page of any professor at a serious research university in your field, and you will find at least several if not dozens of research articles published in journals.

Comment: @MaartenBuis I rethink my answer and actually, I would reply I don't have the idea. The fact I have seen some articles from journals doesn't mean I have seen all articles from these journals and thus, I cannot know whether they publish original research structured with Introduction, Methods, Results, etc. I was reading certain articles that aren't whole journals in my document research process.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I am looking for research articles of a certain structure here. If I go to a web page of any... yes I will find dozens of research articles. But If I don't see them I am not able to determine, what structure they have. And that's the same for Journals. I would need to look at tens of thousands of pages to determine, whether they have a certain structure.

Comment: @Juandev: I'm not in art history (which is the field I'm imagining you're in), but as I understand it, reputable journals in that field tend to have very low acceptance rates.  That's just the nature of the field - papers take years and frequently several rounds of rejections at journals to be published.  There is no magic method around the process.  If you need a paper to be published next year, you needed to have it done several years ago.  There is no fix for not having planned ahead.  Finding a more appropriate journal increases your odds by a few percent, not drastically.

Comment: How does the journal's reputation relate to the structure of the articles @AlexanderWoo?

Comment: Journals typically organize by topic - I hope that is self-explanatory - and prestige - whether they publish the papers the community of researchers on that topic find most interesting, or somewhat less interesting papers, or anything regarded by the community as methodologically sound (whatever that means for that community) and not plagiarized.  Journals typically don't devote themselves to one methodology or another.